# Why is the XML error occurringcvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Status'. One of '{FysiekeID}' is expected

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a table with 6 columns and want to create a XML for it, also for when just one is filled.

I have created an example XML by filling in all the 6 files;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="AssetInterface">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FysiekeID" type="xs:unsignedByte" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="BronID" type="xs:unsignedByte" nillable="true" minOccurs="1"  />
        <xs:element name="Bron" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="Changed" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="true" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="Created" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="true" minOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

With this I get a XML for a full filled object;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<AssetInterface>
    <FysiekeID>1</FysiekeID>
    <BronID>1</BronID>
    <Bron>SAP</Bron>
    <Status>Synchronised</Status>
    <Changed>2021-10-08T04:41:23.617Z</Changed>
    <Created>2021-10-07T20:19:57.003Z</Created>
</AssetInterface>
```

But when I want to create a XML just with the field for Status, I got an error;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><AssetInterface><Status>_New</Status></AssetInterface>

Error occurred while parsing xml: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Status'. One of '{FysiekeID}' is expected.
```

I read several topics that the XSD should be changed, added those nilleable and minoccurs tags but still no difference. What is the correct way to handle this message?

Comment: minOccurs="1" means that the minimum number of occurrences is one, so you will get an error if the element is absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will change `minOccurs="1"` to `minOccurs="0"` , it will make the XML elements optional.